# why prokaryotic ribosomes have 30s and40s subunits and eukaryotic ribosomes have 40sand 60s subunits?

Tags: cell-biology

Ribosomes are protein factories of cell and are composed of two subunits; one smaller and other larger unit I want to know that why ,ribosomes of eukaryotes have a 40s and 60s subunit and prokaryotic ribosomes have 30s and50s subunits ?If we combine 30s and 50s subunits shouldn't it be 80s ribosome instead of 70s ribosome .

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you asking why there is difference between prokaryotic and eukaryotic ribosomal subunit masses? Or do you simply wanna know why these numbers dont add up?

Comment: I want to know why these numbers donot add up?I know that difference in their masses is due to difference of masses of their proteins.(of subunits).

Comment: Mass and sedimentation-coefficients are not the same thing, although related.

Answer (score 2):

I think I can get the point after your second comment.

Not only protein composition, but rRNA composition and sequence length of Bacterial and Eukaryotic ribosome is very different. And the difference of sequence lengths (and hence mass) in **both** take part in the difference.

Answer (score 1):

The S units are an artifact of the historical way these RNAs were characterized, based on the rate at which they sediment in an ultracentrifuge. S stands for Svedberg, which is a non-metric unit that measures sedimentation rate, based on size and shape. Larger molecules sediment slower. A better way to refer to ribosomal subunits is by calling them large subunit (LSU), and small subunit (SSU), because ALL ribosomes consist of one SSU and one LSU. Even the 5.8S is simply a part of eukaryotic LSU. Put subunits together and the shape changes, so it they would not sediment at a rate equal to the sum of each subunit.

Comment: You mean sedimentation depends on shape of subunits as they combine they slightly change their shape and will now sediment at 70s instead of 80s?